# Changing selection color in exporting ArcMap layout with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, select, layouts

I use ArcMap and am looking for a way to change the selection color that would be respected when exporting map layouts programmatically using `arcpy.mapping.ExportToPNG()`. Currently, it is always the light green color (the default selection color in ArcMap).

[image]

Changing a selection color in ArcMap (`Selection` menu > `Selection Options`) does change the selection color but it is only respected when exporting the layout manually from the `File` menu or when exporting  the layout in the Python window (it respects the selection color set in ArcMap since I am inside a live ArcMap session). Exporting a layout using `arcpy` though always uses the default light green color for selection.

I have found no other settings in the ArcMap menus that would help and `AdvancedArcMapSettings` utility does not have any either.

Is there any way to make `arcpy` export layouts using any other selection color than the default light green one?

Comment: i think there is a workaround see here: https://community.esri.com/thread/117867

Comment: Alternatively you could try to represent your selection as a definition query on a second layer with the same data source.

Comment: @Geo.Dude, thanks a ton for the link, this was helpful and got me started.

Comment: @PolyGeo, good idea, this has also moved me into the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `arcpy.mapping.Layer` object does not expose the selection symbol property according to the docs of the [`Layer`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer.htm):

> Not all layer properties are accessible through the Layer object.
>   There are many properties available in the ArcMap Layer Properties
>   dialog box that are not exposed to the arcpy scripting environment
>   (for example, display properties, field aliases, **selection symbology**,
>   and so on).

Adding duplicate layers pointing to the same data source and setting the definition queries sounds really cumbersome, particularly when I don't know beforehand what layers I will need to run selection on.

I have solved it in another way.

1. I pre-create three layers for each of the shape types (point, polyline, and polygon) using the necessary selection symbology.
2. Before the export of the map document, I duplicate the layer that I will run selections on and update its symbology using the `.lyr` file.
3. Then I set definition query on the dummy layer that will serve as a selection symbol layer only.

All of this is done programmatically, so the only thing I really need to supply is the name of the layer that selections will run on.

The full script:

```
'''
Script that demonstrates how to use predefined layer files (.lyr)
to change the selection symbol for any map document layer. The
selection symbol is not exposed via `arcpy.mapping.Layer` object, so
it is necessary to emulate the selection using another layer drawn
on top of the layer that you targeting your selection against.

The script assumes that you have prepared beforehand 3 layers (.lyr
files) for each shape type (point, polyline, polygon).
'''

import arcpy
import arcpy.mapping as mp


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def get_layer_shape_type(mxd, layer_name):
    """return shape type of layer in the operational map document"""
    lyr = mp.ListLayers(mxd, layer_name)[0]
    return arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType.lower()


#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def main():
    # name of the layer that will have selections
    base_layer_name = 'cities'

    # name of the layer that will be drawn on top emulating the selection symbol
    select_layer_name = base_layer_name + '_selection'

    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r'C:\GIS\Temp\export_selection.mxd')
    df = mp.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

    # get the right layer based on shape type of the base layer
    lyr_template = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r'C:\GIS\Temp\{}.lyr'.format(
        get_layer_shape_type(mxd, base_layer_name)))

    # copy the TOC layer that will have selections to the top of TOC
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, mp.ListLayers(mxd, base_layer_name)[0], 'TOP')

    # rename the newly copied layer
    mp.ListLayers(mxd, base_layer_name)[0].name = select_layer_name

    # update the symbology of the newly copied layer to have the needed
    # selection symbol
    mp.UpdateLayer(
        df,
        mp.ListLayers(mxd, select_layer_name)[0],
        lyr_template,
        symbology_only=True)

    print mp.ListLayers(mxd)
    # [<map layer u'cities_selected'>, <map layer u'cities'>]

    lyr_base = mp.ListLayers(mxd, base_layer_name)[0]
    lyr_selection = mp.ListLayers(mxd, select_layer_name)[0]

    # doing selection on the base layer
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(
        in_layer_or_view=lyr_base,
        selection_type='NEW_SELECTION',
        where_clause=" STATE_NAME = 'Oregon' ")
    df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()

    print lyr_base.getSelectionSet()
    #[3129L, 3130L, 3131L, 3132L]

    # limiting the features to be drawn in the layer with selection symbol
    lyr_selection.definitionQuery = "OBJECTID in ({})".format(
        ','.join([str(i) for i in lyr_base.getSelectionSet()]))

    # clearing selection of the base layer
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(
        in_layer_or_view=lyr_base, selection_type='CLEAR_SELECTION')

    # exporting the map
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    mp.ExportToPNG(mxd, r'C:\GIS\Temp\sel_prog_{}.png'.format(base_layer_name))


main()
```